# Why the dot notation in bracket represent itself instead of any single character except newline or line terminator

Tags: javascript, regex

With javascript,  I find the dot notation have three ways to use. eg:

```
/./.test('1'); //true
/\./.test('.'); //true
/[.]/.test('1'); //false
/[.]/.test('.'); //true
```

Comment: This is not JavaScript specific, that's how regex works.

Comment: This is easily searchable using "regex dot meaning".

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html

Comment: [http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html), As stated in the given link documentation `The dot matches a single character, without caring what that character is. The only exception are line break characters.` which should answer your question provided in your topic.

Comment: If it still meant 'any character' when inside a character class, it would defeat the purpose of putting it into a character class, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the brackets represent a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), that defines a set of characters to be matched. Inside a character class the meaning of characters is normally the character itself.

**regular-expression.info:**

> In most regex flavors, the only special characters or metacharacters inside a character class are the closing bracket (]), the backslash (), the caret (^), and the hyphen (-). The [usual metacharacters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special) are normal characters inside a character class, and do not need to be escaped by a backslash.

In regular expressions you have **two** ways to use the dot. Either the meta character, that matches any other character except .... or you want to match a dot literally then you usually escape it or put it in a character class. Many people use `[.]` instead of `\.` in their regular expressions to match a literal dot, because they say it is more readable.